# Make PCLinux Always Boot to XTerm?

Tags: linux, kde, xterm, pclinuxos

My PCLinux system occasionally boots to (after login on the regular login screen) two white xterm windows with grey scrollbars on their lefts and NO system buttons (maximize,minimize,etc.) This screen does not have any of the normal KDE buttons, simply two frameless xterm windows on the default desktop background, no menubar, no nothing. I find this layout particularily useful, is there a way to always boot to this, and perhaps also somehow remove the regular desktop (KDE) from memory entirely to save space?
I am not familiar with booting or Desktop environments. The reason I want it to keep this thing that appears to be a bug is because I use the small one in the bottom left to monitor server logs and the top left one to work on a server.

Comment: At startt You get Desktop managet (graphic login screen) ? What is your distro?

Comment: [PCLinuxOS](http://pclinuxos.com) with KDE.

Comment: this info (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=563563) about KDM (K Desktop Manager) can be useful to make own minimalistic environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove KDE, but if you like Xterm so much (who does not, really) you need to replace it with another graphical desktop.

The reason your PC occasionally boots with XTerm is probably because you left them open before you logged off, and KDE is set to remember your desktops.

Again, if you remove KDE you need to pick another desktop, I use Xfce on Debian since forever so I highly recommend it. I never used PCLinuxOS or KDE, but here is what I suggest, all of this should work.

First install Xfce:
http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=105496.0
or, synaptic > Settings > Repositories > Section xfce4

Before anything else try Xfce by switching your default desktop (log out, and select Xfce before logging in, or change it by whatever interface KDE uses for a login manager)

Removing KDE is trickier since Synaptic is PART of KDE, so you first need to logout KDE to the terminal. Again, I never used KDE, but as I understand KDE is going to return you to run level 3 upon LOGOFF, which is the single-user console. If not, issue the command "init 3" as root in the xterm which will most certainly get it done.

Then visit this page which is Ubuntu but both PCLinuxOS and Ubuntu are using the same package managers (apt-get). You are also going to read some warnings as well about what you are considering to do. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed

Then in Xfce go to Settings > Session and Startup, and make sure the "Automatically save session on logout" is ticked, and leave the Xterms open before you log off. They will be there when you return.

Comment: how to open synpatic from terminal? - found it: 'init 3' > login > 'kde' > click icon.

Comment: The instructions in the link to askubuntu.com state that there are missing packages.

Comment: "sudo apt-get remove kde-full", or "su apt-get remove kde-full" if you do not have sudo installed

Answer (score 0):

To get it You need to look at Desrtop Manager configuration or if there no DM at X session configuration.

But, bacause You anyway need some window manager, to be able to move and resize windows, You can try different Desktop environment, as LXDE (classic) or Xmonad (tiled).

So. If one terminal is enough for You, You can change default runlevel to not load X-server at all and get black screen with text login.

Comment: How would I do this?